# Generate QR code only with 1 string

Tags: arrays, android-intent, qr-code

i´m creating an app where you fill up a form, and press a button to generats a QR Code from it. My problem is that i can do it with 1 string, but i need the 7 Strings (7 itens from form). i´ve tried to put "[]" where it asks for String, it gets no erro or crash, but always comes with 1.

```
 - MainActivity intent

        QR.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {/*Ação do botão gerar código*/

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                Intent intentQR = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        QRActivity.class);
                intentQR.putExtra("id", v.getId());
                startActivity(intentQR);

            }
        });
```

- QRActivity (where the code shown, its the example with String[],in the code below where is written "array", was "nameInput")

  public class QRActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

  ```
  View view;
  ShareScreen screen;
  private String LOG_TAG ="aqui";


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_qr);
      view = (View) findViewById(R.id.QrRelative);// your layout id


      int caller = getIntent().getIntExtra("id",0);


      switch (caller) {
          case R.id.generateCode:
              String array[] = new String[7];
              String nameInput = MainActivity.name.getText().toString();
              array[0]= nameInput;
              String con1Input = MainActivity.contact1.getText().toString();
              array[1]= con1Input;
              String con2Input = MainActivity.contact2.getText().toString();
              array[2]= con2Input;
              String con3Input = MainActivity.contact3.getText().toString();
              array[3]= con3Input;
              String bloodInput = MainActivity.blood.getText().toString();
              array[4]= bloodInput;
              String allergyInput = MainActivity.allergy.getText().toString();
              array[5]= allergyInput;
              String infoInput = MainActivity.info.getText().toString();
              array[6]= infoInput;
              Log.v(LOG_TAG,nameInput);

              WindowManager windowQR = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
              Display displayQR = windowQR.getDefaultDisplay();
              Point pointQR = new Point();
              displayQR.getSize(pointQR);
              int width = pointQR.x;
              int height = pointQR.y;
              int smallerDimension = width < height ? width : height;
              smallerDimension = smallerDimension * 3 / 4;
              QRCodeEncoder qrCodeEncoder = new QRCodeEncoder(array, null, Contents.Type.TEXT, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE.toString(), smallerDimension);
              try {

                  Bitmap bitmap = qrCodeEncoder.encodeAsBitmap();
                  ImageView imageQR = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageQR);
                  imageQR.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
              } catch (WriterException e) {
                  e.printStackTrace();
              }
              break;
      }


  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to create a [java object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) an [parcel](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) it.  E.g:

```
public class Category implements Parcelable {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = Category.class.getSimpleName();

    private String id;
    private String name;

    public Category() {
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public Category(Parcel origin) {
        setId(origin.readString());
        setName(origin.readString());
    }

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeString(id);
        dest.writeString(name);
    }

    public static final Creator<Category> CREATOR = new Creator<Category>() {
        @Override
        public Category createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
            return new Category(source);
        }

        @Override
        public Category[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Category[size];
        }
    };
}
```

Then, you can instantiate your model and include it on your intent. Android works nice with parcels.

```
Category category = new Category();
category.setName("Some name");
Intentent intentQR = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                        QRActivity.class);
                intentQR.putExtra("extra_category", category);
                startActivity(intentQR);
```

Comment: I appreciate your help, but i don´t get it... It does not generate the QR code anymore, sorry i´m very newbe on this develop thing

Comment: in other activity, how do i use this parcel ?